# Add CSS styling to output jquery

Tags: java, jquery, css, mobile

I am working on my JQuery mobile app for my blog and trying to add a bit of css to the blog output.

I have the following custom js code:

```
function listPosts(data) {
var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
$.each(data.posts,function(key,val) {

    output += '<li>';
    output += '<a href="#bpost" onclick="displayPost(' + val.id + ')">';
    output += '<h3>' + val.title + '</h3>';
    output += '<span class="ui-li-count">' + val.comment_count + '</span>';

    output += '<p class="postedon" >Posted on ' + val.date.substring(0,10) +
```

The class="postedon" as a css style to change the date output color to Red but the problem I am having is both the dates and the text 'Posted on' are showing Red.

How do I style this to avoid the text 'Posted on' color been changed to Red.

Answer (score 1):

Try this wrap the date with a span and add class to it

```
 output += '<p>Posted on <span class="postedon">' + val.date.substring(0,10) + '</span>'+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `span` element around the date and then target it in your css like this:

```
p.postedon span {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

CSS:

```
.postedon {
color:black;
}
.postedon span {
color: red;
}
```

Code

```
function listPosts(data) {
var output='<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
$.each(data.posts,function(key,val) {

    output += '<li>';
    output += '<a href="#bpost" onclick="displayPost(' + val.id + ')">';
    output += '<h3>' + val.title + '</h3>';
    output += '<span class="ui-li-count">' + val.comment_count + '</span>';

    output += '<p class="postedon" >Posted on <span>' + val.date.substring(0,10) + '</span>' +
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yk7St/

Comment: You guys are amazing... 

Used this from first reply:

 output += '<p>Posted on <span class="postedon">' + val.date.substring(0,10) + '</span>';